# Uploading Image to server doesn't work unless the first request is made from postman

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I have written the following code to upload a profile image using Alamofire. Now the problem is that when I upload an image, the API get executed successfully but the image not gets uploaded. But if the same thing I do once I upload the image from Postman then the same code starts working. Why? Is there any issue in my code. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
let parameters = [
        "contact_no": user.mobile,
        "first_name": user.firstName,
        "last_name": user.lastName,
        "email_id": user.email,
        "gender_id": user.gender,
        "device_id": deviceId,
        "state_id": user.stateID,
        "city_id": user.cityID,
    ]
    let credentialData = "\(constants.username):\(constants.password)".data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!

    let base64Credentials = credentialData.base64EncodedString()

    let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"
    ]
     let image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImg.image!)

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ (multipartFormData) in
                       multipartFormData.append(image!, withName: "profile_image", fileName: "test.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
            },usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                         to:url,
                         method:.post,
                         headers:headers,
                         encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                            vwWait.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(UIView.removeFromSuperview), with: nil, waitUntilDone: false)
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.responseJSON { response in
                                    debugPrint(response)

                                    self.getProfileData()
                                }
                            case .failure(let encodingError):
                                print(encodingError)
                            }

    })
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is related or not, but try to reduce your image size before passing in api or increase upload size at server side, May be may be this is size issue.

Comment: Hi, Check this code, Its gonna work sure. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650584/swift-4-get-an-upload-image-progress-using-urlsession/53650851#53650851

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Thanks. I will reduce the size and check if it is uploading or not.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati I tried reducing size but profile image is not getting uploaded.

Comment: @AbdulHoqueNuri. Thanks. I am trying with your code and will let you know if it works.

Comment: @NishigandhaAhire sure :)

Comment: try check with backend whether they getting image that your passing or not, or try to send very small image

Comment: The issue was resolved when I changed the format from PNG to JPEG. For JPEG the image got uploaded. It also scaled the image reducing size.  `let image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImg.image!, 0.025)`