# Alamofire upload image corrupted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I have function uploading image using Alamofire.
When I upload it, the image is corrupted. But when I'm save it to device, the image can be opened.

Here's the upload code

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (_multipartFormData:MultipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            if key == "foto_id" {
                _multipartFormData.append(
                    "\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
                    withName: key,
                    fileName: "_foto_id.png",
                    mimeType: "image/png"
                )
            } else if key == "foto_selfie" {
                _multipartFormData.append(
                    "\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
                    withName: key,
                    fileName: "_foto_selfie.png",
                    mimeType: "image/png"
                )
            } else {
                //Data other than image
                _multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }, usingThreshold: 1, to: BASE_URL, method: .post) { (encodingResult:SessionManager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult) in

        switch encodingResult {


        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseObject{(response: DataResponse<clsResponsePostFotoID>) in

                let reqLoginResponse = response.result.value

                completionHandler(reqLoginResponse, nil)

            }
            break

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
            //                completionHandler(nil,encodingError as NSError?)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `"\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!` into `value as! Data`, it'll show error

`Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Data?, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'`

`Overloads for 'append' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Data, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String), (URL, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)`

How can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Check this code, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53650584/swift-4-get-an-upload-image-progress-using-urlsession/53650851#53650851

Comment: `"\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,`, No. You are using `description`, clearly not recommended. What's the class of `value`?` Data`? `NSData`? `UIImage`?

Comment: @A.H.Nuri Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Data?, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
if let image = value as? UIImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6) {
    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: key, fileName: key+".jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Any, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'

Answer (score 0):

your code is kinda mess and make it clear and formatted first. Btw, just try with my code:

```
var imageFrontData: Data?
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    var uploadImage = WMCameraUtils.fixOrientation((info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage)!)
    imageFrontData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uploadImage, 1.0)!
    self.uploadFile()
}

static func fixOrientation(_ img:UIImage) -> UIImage {
    if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.up) {
        return img;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, false, img.scale);
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)
    img.draw(in: rect)

    let normalizedImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}

func uploadFile() {
    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            /* self.imageFrontData is image data object */
            if let data = self.imageFrontData {
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "front-photo", fileName: "front-photo.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: key)
            }
    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: uploadURL!, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let err = response.error {

                }
                /* do rest */
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            /* error */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ` multipartFormData.append((value?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)!, withName: key)` changed into `((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)`

Comment: crash at `((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)`

Comment: @Renzrz Could you do same as what I did? I've edited my answer. It's working seamlessly.

Comment: Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Any, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)' on `                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "front-photo", fileName: "front-photo.png", mimeType: "image/png")`

I don't know whats wrong with alamofire in this project.
When i make new project, the `multipartFormData.append` can use `data` or `value as! Data`
but when i use this project, the alamofire always show error Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(Data, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)'

Answer (score 0):

Answering late but might help others.

When uploading image as multipart and you have string bytes, **encode it with base64 instead of utf8.**

```
extension String {
var base64Data: Data? {
    return Data.init(base64Encoded: self, options: .init(rawValue: 0))
   }
}
```

for example:

```
"\(bytes)".base64Data
```