# Send file or image using Alamofire multipart form data iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file-upload, alamofire, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file which can be an image (jpg or png) or it can be a file(txt or pdf) using Alamofire multipart form data. How can I differentiate wether it is a file or an image?
Here is the code to upload a file the resume for now it is an image but I want it to be both image or a file

```
func postResume(resume: UIImage)
{
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]
    
    let url = Constants.BASEURL.baseUrl + Constants.URLEXTENSIONS.getAnswers
    
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: {(multipartFormData) in
        
        let imageData = resume.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        
        if let data = imageData
        {
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "resume", fileName: "resume.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        
    }, to: url,headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               
            }
            break
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: In your code it is always an image?. if you want to pass anything in, convert the file to data and pass the data and mimeType in as params

Comment: you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650851/6681858

Comment: how would I know the mimeType is wether image/jpg or a pdf from the data ?

Comment: Hassnain, in the closure provided by `upload` it's _you_ who provides the data from a specific file. You should know from the file extension or by other knowledge (the file is on the device?) what the file contains, unless you get some data from _elsewhere_, where you don't know what it contains. There is also a way to retrieve a MIME type from a file extension. If this is your question, please be more precise. ;)